# How to write this expression functionally?

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming

I want to rewrite the following python code functionally:

```
lst = [0.0] * 10
for pos in [2,5]:
    lst[pos] = 1.0
```

This is my attempt, but is incorrect:

```
lst = (lambda zeros:
          map(
              lambda pos: zeros[pos] = 1.0, [2,5])
      )([0.0] * 10)
```

The error I get is `lambda cannot contain assignment`.

Using list comprehension, the solution is:

```
lst = [ 1.0 if x in [2,5] else 0.0 for x in range(10) ]
```

Comment: _How_ is it incorrect? Does it throw an exception or give the wrong answer? Either way, **include that in your question**.

Comment: `lst = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` ;)

Comment: Your list comprehension is more functional because it does not destroy the input. A very important component of functional programming is immutability and referential transparency. This assures expressions are interchangeable. Even in Haskell, list comprehensions are extremely handy and very functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do prefer the list comprehension in your own answer, but if I were to do it with more of a functional touch, I think I would use a `lambda` function and a `map`:

```
lazy = map(lambda element: 1 if element in [2,5] else 0, range(10))
```

Note that `map` is a lazy iterator in Python 3. If you want an evaluated `list` you have to enclose the line in an explicit `list(...)` constructor:

```
lst = list(map(lambda element: 1 if element in [2,5] else 0, range(10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension method is probably better, but if you're looking for functional how about this:

```
lst = [0.0] * 10
lst = map(lambda (i, x): 1.0 if i in {2,5} else x, enumerate(lst))
#[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

By using `enumerate(lst)` as the iterable for `map()`, we get both the index and the value. In this case, we yield 0 if `i` is in `{2, 5}`. Otherwise we keep the value `x`.

If you're using python3, you have to wrap the call to `map()` with `list()`. However, that approach is [not recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) as it wastefully creates a list.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is with generic function `unfold`

```
def unfold (f, acc):
  return f ( lambda x, next: [x] + unfold (f, next)
           , lambda x: [x] 
           , acc                          
           )

def main (ones):
  def value (i):
    return 1 if i in ones else 0   
  return unfold ( lambda next, done, i:
                    done (value (i)) if i >= 10 else next (value (i), i + 1)
                , 0
                )

print (main ( { 2, 5 }))
# [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

`unfold` can be used in interesting ways

```
def alphabet ():
  return unfold ( lambda next, done, c:
                    done (c)            
                      if c == 'z' else
                        next (c, chr (ord (c) + 1))
                , 'a'
                )

print (alphabet ())
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Python's lambda syntax is really rigid its awkward ternary syntax make functional expressions painful to write. In the example below, we pre-define a function `gen` using some imperative syntaxes to help readability, then we pass it to `unfold` - this program also shows that `state` can be a complex value

```
def fib (n):
  def gen (next, done, state):
    (n, a, b) = state
    if n == 0:
      return done (a)
    else:
      return next (a, (n - 1, b, a + b))
  return unfold (gen, (n, 0, 1))

print (fib (20))
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765]
```

Of course all of this pain exists for a reason - it's a signal indicating that we're doing something wrong. A seasoned python programmer would never write `main`, `alphabet`, or `fib` like we did above. So it's not *pythonic* (as they say), but it's *functional*, and hopefully that answers your question.

---

Below, we dramatically simplify `unfold` - instead of passing `next` and `done` helpers to the user lambda, we ask the user to return a tuple that encodes their choice: `(value, None)` says `value` is the last value in the sequence, `(value, nextState)` will produce the next value and continue with the next state.

The trade-off here is the `unfold` is a little less complicated, but it requires the user to know the special tuple signalling to write their program. Before, `next` and `done` kept this worry out of the user's mind. Either way is fine, I share this just to give another alternative

```
def unfold (f, acc):
  (x, nextAcc) = f (acc)
  if nextAcc is None:
    return [x]
  else:
    return [x] + unfold (f, nextAcc)

def fib (n):
  def gen (state):
    (n, a, b) = state
    if n == 0:
      return (a, None)
    else:
      return (a, (n - 1, b, a + b))
  return unfold (gen, (n, 0, 1))

print (fib (20))
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765]
```